# Why did Tony Stark design the Hulkbuster armor?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

What was the reason that Tony Stark designed the Hulkbuster armor in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*?

Was it made specially for controlling the Hulk, or was there a some other specific reason behind it?

Comment: To bust the Hulk?

Comment: Because the sole idea was so cool that he couldn't deny it ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Tony Stark worked with Bruce Banner himself on the Hulkbuster armor (affectionately known as Veronica) in order to stop the Hulk if he ever got out of control.

You have to remember that Bruce Banner neither trusts nor likes The Hulk as he doesn't really have much, if any, control over the Hulk after he has 'hulked out'. When the Helicarrier is attacked by Loki in *The Avengers*, we see that after transforming into the Hulk, Hulk attacks friends and foe alike, wrecking a large portion of the Helicarrier, hurting allies and eventually smashing a building to rubble after he is drawn away from the Helicarrier.

Although the Hulk is much more focused in the Battle of New York at the end of *The Avengers* and in the assault on the Sokovian castle at the start of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Bruce will always be wary of the fact that he is not in control after 'hulking out', and is painfully aware of the death, destruction and devastation that the Hulk has caused in the past.

> "The last time I was in New York I kind of broke... Harlem"

Naturally, Bruce wants a contingency plan in case the Hulk ever goes off on a rampage again. That plan takes the form of a new Iron Man suit designed specifically to be able to fight the Hulk - a good job too, given the events in Johannesburg in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Comment: I disagree with the "good job' part - totally wrong approach. You should not make the Hulk *more* angry if you want him to stop. My assumption was that Tony just built it because it was cool.

Comment: @kaay I meant that it was a good job that they had a plan, not that the Hulkbuster did a good job.

Comment: @kaay is that a troll comment? have you seen the film? Bruce and Tony have a conversation specifically about Veronica and how they both designed it together.

Comment: @kaay I will agree that the Hulkbuster should probably have been painted a pastel blue-lilac, and have the ability to get the Hulk away from things rather than punch. But it looked so cool...

Comment: @kaay They were redirecting the Hulk using his anger.  If they don't get him to attack the hulk buster, then he continues to hurt the people he doesn't want to hurt and will (and did) drive him away from the avengers. The plan *was* to use his anger as a lever to manipulate the Hulk, then drag him to a remote location where he could cool off.  So for that purpose it actually did work - and making him more angry was necessary for it to work.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I see the point you are making, but I *do* have to point out that there's no reason Tony could not have built it in collaboration with Bruce **and** he just built it because it was cool.  Tony's not one to shy away from a win-win, especially when it means building a giant robot.

Comment: I concede the point. I've only seen the movie once.
Bruce isn't exactly level-headed when it comes to this matter, though, so Tony may still have had the most influence on the *form* Veronica has taken.